# Does a machine have to be domain joined in order to use Direct Access

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2008-r2, direct-access

Does a machine (e.g., mobile laptop) have to be domain joined in order to use Direct Access (DA)? Or does DA allow the user to provide credentials just like VPN does when setting up DA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"DirectAccess clients must be members of an Active Directory domain."

Sources:

- MS DirectAccess Technical Overview Doc: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=64966e88-1377-4d1a-be86-ab77014495f4&displaylang=en
- https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/10things/?p=1371

Comment: Thx.

Does it have to be the same domain as the server providing DA? E.g. can consultants use DA from their machine which might be joined to their consulting companies AD rather than the customer's AD?

Comment: The DA and the clients should belong to the same domain.

Comment: Yes they would need to be on the same domain. You might be able to provide access to resources on both domains/networks using one DA Server if there was an existing VPN/trusted sites configuration between the two locations in place, however I am unable to verify or prove that.